# Move shapefile upper and lower corner points

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile that has been generated by an internal tool and had missing shx and dbf files but I was able to generate it using the post in the below link:

http://geospatialpython.com/2011/11/generating-shapefile-shx-files.html

However, when trying to perform spatial join with a set of points it returns null.

Upon checking out and comparing with normal shp files I found that upper and lower left and right points are very large

Example upper left is

```
-327802.687478,+3530832.250432
```

Is there a way to change those boundaries so I can perform spatial join or reproject the points I wish to do spatial join

I am using gvSIG and QGIS.

Comment: If you only have a file with a `.shp` suffix, which has no attributes or spatial reference or correct geometry, you do NOT have a *shapefile*, just a file with a .shp suffix. You need to review what that internal tool is writing, to see if there is anything of value in it, then alter the tool to generate a valid shapefile in a known coordinate system.

Comment: Those coordinates look like they're in a projected coordinate system. The units could be meters or feet.